# Why is Python Beautiful Soup stripping parameters from the scraped URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape this website with Python BeautifulSoup. And my code below is first fetching all the links from the page. While fetching the links it is stripping ampersands and parameters from the original link. I wonder why? Would somebody know? I've got the code down here along with the output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = requests.get ("http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/demand_emp_demand.aspx?lflag=eng&file1=dmd&fin=2017-2018&fin_year=2017-2018&source=national&Digest=x44uSVqhiyzomN66Te0ELQ")
soup = bs(url.text, 'xml')
state= soup.find(id = "t1")
state_links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href= True):

    state_links.append(link['href'])
    state_links = [e for e in state_links if e not in ("javascript:history.go(-1);", "http://164.100.129.6/netnrega/MISreport4.aspx?fin_year=2013-2014rpt=RP&source=national", "javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinkButton1','')")]

for dis_link in state_links:
    # print (dis_link)
    link_new = "http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/"+dis_link
    print (link_new)
```

Output:

**Actual Link:** http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/demand_emp_demand.aspx?file1=dmd**&page1**=s&**lflag**=eng&**state_name**=ANDHRA+PRADESH&**state_code**=02&**fin_year**=2017-2018&source=national&Digest=4jL5hchs+iT7xqB6T/UXzw

(Highlighted stuff in code is missing from the scraped link)

**Scraped link:** http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/demand_emp_demand.aspx?file1=dmd=s=eng=ANDHRA+PRADESH=02=2017-2018=national=4jL5hchs+iT7xqB6T/UXzw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because you are trying to parse it with 'xml', instead try to parse it with 'html.parser',

I am getting the following result with the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = requests.get ("http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/ne....")
soup = bs(url.text, 'html.parser')
state_links = []
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    state_links.append(link['href'])

print(state_links)
# 'demand_emp_demand.aspx?file1=dmd&page1=s&lflag=eng&state_name=ANDHRA+PRADESH&state_code=02&fin_year=2017-2018&source=national&Digest=4jL5hchs+iT7xqB6T/UXzw'
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is about the parser used in Beautifulsoup.

Try with

```
soup = bs(url.text, 'html.parser')
```

or

```
soup = bs(url.text, 'lxml')
```

You might need to install some specific parser, see this [chapter of the doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).